# DataContext's Connection string help

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, connection-string, datacontext

I have the following connection string: `"Data Source=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;"`, it complains that `''` is an invalid username. I can't quite remember the user name or password commands, nor can i remember if there's anything else i'm missing. Can someone help?

Comment: [http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest option is to use Integrated Security:

```
@"Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=true"
```